# Time efficiency of integer to string

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

```
int i = 5;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(i);
String s = "" + i;
String k = Integer.toString(i);
String u = String.valueOf(i);
```

Which of these would be the most efficient to convert int to a String in **java**? Are there any other more efficient methods?

Comment: Why don't you read the source code? (and I doubt that there are any significant differences between the two)

Comment: To prevent anti-patterns, `Integer#toString` would probably be the best choice.

Comment: This is micro-optimization. It's highly likely that there are better optimization opportunities in your program.

Comment: You shouldn’t worry. Better worry which is the clearest and most readable. IMHO they are all fine, though, but `"" + i` is frowned upon by some.

Answer (score 5):

It is highly recommended and encouraged to go through javadocs and source code.

First of all, `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(i);` will create a StringBuilder of size `i` with no value. So correct one is `new StringBuilder(String str)` to create a new `StringBuilder` of same value as `str`

Second, `+` operator uses toString() method of objects to convert the argument to string.

Third, `Integer.toString(i);` and `String.valueOf(i);` are same. Under the hood `String.valueof(int i)` invokes `Integer.toString(i)`

So using `Integer.toString(i)` make more sense as it'll  be more readable and indicating the intent of changing an integer to string.